# Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove there exists an integer $a$ such that $p\mid (a^2-a+3)$ iff there exists an integer $b$ such that $p\mid(b^2-b+25)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that there exists an integer $a$ such that $p\mid(a^2-a+3)$ if and only if there exists an integer $b$ such that $p\mid(b^2-b+25)$.

I'm getting a bit confused with this problem. I was trying to show first the case $(\Longrightarrow)$ by factoring $a^2-a+3= (a-1)(a-3)+3a$, which would imply that $p\vert(a-1), p\vert(a-3)$ and $p\vert3a$. Looking at the last condition $p\vert3a$ it seems that this would only be true if $p=3$?

Similarly for $(\Longleftarrow)$ the term $b^2-b+25$ factors as $(b-1)(b-25)+25b$ which would imply also that $p\mid(b-1), p\mid t(b-25)$ and $p\mid 25b$.

Is this going anywhere or should I consider something else?

Comment: Since it's contest-math, please provide a source so that we know it's not an ongoing contest.

Comment: The problem was on aops. It stated the following "This problem originally appeared on a contest used to determine the Chinese national team.", but I don't have the knowledge on which year it was. It's from the Volume 2 book.

Comment: I wish you had written something easier to check, but that's a known problem indeed: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c308833_2016_spain_mathematical_olympiad

Comment: You may find that completing the square is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Work in the field $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. $a^2-a+3$ has a root if & only if  $\Delta_a=-11\mod p$ is a square, whereas $b^2-b+25$ has a root if & only $\Delta_b=-99\mod p$ is a square.